# Ebay Find API parse error Document is empty, line 1

Tags: python, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm trying to use FindingAPI but im getting this error on with PROD credentials. I think the problem is within the API.

My code is just a simple:

```
try:
    api = Connection(config_file='ebay.dev.yml',  domain="api.ebay.com", debug=True, iteid='EBAY-US', escape_xml=False)
    request = {
        'keywords': "go pro 8",
        'itemFilter': [
            {'name': 'Condition', 'value': 'used'},
            {'name': 'SoldItemsOnly', 'value': 'true'}
        ],
        'paginationInput': {
            'entriesPerPage': 1,
            'pageNumber': 1
        },
        'sortOrder': 'PricePlusShippingLowest'
    }


    response = api.execute('findCompletedItems', request)
    print(response)

except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())
```

This gives me this error:

```
2020-11-13 06:02:36,022 ebaysdk [DEBUG]:status code=202
2020-11-13 06:02:36,022 ebaysdk [DEBUG]:headers={'Date': 'Thu, 12 Nov 2020 22:02:36 GMT', 'Server': 'Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000'}
2020-11-13 06:02:36,023 ebaysdk [DEBUG]:content=
2020-11-13 06:02:36,023 ebaysdk [DEBUG]:response parse failed: Document is empty, line 1, column 1 (<string>, line 1)
2020-11-13 06:02:36,024 ebaysdk [ERROR]:findCompletedItems: Accepted
'findCompletedItems: Accepted'
{'findCompletedItemsResponse': 'parse error Document is empty, line 1, column 1 (<string>, line 1)'}
```

Anyone has an idea how to make this succeed? What I tried is adjusting the **ebay yml**, and that seems to work fine with **TradingAPI** calls but not with this **FindingAPI** for some reason. I already checked the github repo for issues related and I also coulnd'nt find one

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your import.
Your import probably be "from ebaysdk.trading import Connection", you need to change it to
"from ebaysdk.finding import Connection"